# rsync - how do I run commands 1 after another?

Tags: rsync

I want to run multiple commands.  They don't need to run at the same time.  Just run command 1, then command 2, etc.

```
rsync -az -P live/ test1/
rsync -az -P live/ test2/
```

Is there a way to do this without waiting for the first command to finish and then entering the second command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy,

`rsync -az -P live/ test1/; rsync -az -P live/ test2/`

This will run `test1` wait, then run `test2`.

Comment: @Nick Bull He means manually type the command. Having it on the same line with a `;` will run it after test1 completes.

Comment: Right, just got that, apologies!

Comment: @NickBull no problem, thanks for removing your downvote

Answer (score 0):

Run them as background processes using `&`:

```
rsync -az -P live/ test1/ &
rsync -az -P live/ test2/ &
```

They are now running in the background! Should output something like:

```
[4] 9434
```

for each, where

- `[4]` is used to get the process back to the foreground using `fg 4` (i.e., running in the foreground in the shell); press `CTRL+Z` to pause it. Then to resume and start again in the background using `bg 4`.
- `9434` is the PID.